# How to change formatting of export file in dhtmlxgrid?

Tags: php, css, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxgrid for displaying data for my reports. I have embedded two export buttons i.e. pdf and excel. But there are some number fields which are left aligned in exported file. I want to change the alignment of the number fields to the right as well as I want to set the width of the columns(if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can change column types to number based ones ( edn or ron ), it will change align of data in those columns in case of export to Excel

Comment: I have tried this and it aligned the data to the right. But when I applied mygrid.setNumberFormat("0,000.0",2); ... it again aligned back to left. Because I think it is considering 1,220,00.00 (data with commas) as strings and aligning it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a lot of debugging and a little customization to get column alignment and widths to work how I wanted them do. I have this working in production, but not sure if it will fit your case. This is with dhtmlxgrid v4.1 and I'm using the Java back-end Excel writer classes.

**On the front end**
 
You should debug through dhtmlxgrid_export.js in this function:

```
dhtmlXGridObject.prototype._serialiseExportConfig
```

Make sure your alignments are correct in this array:

```
this.cellAlign[i]
```

If they aren't, you probably need to explicitly set them when you create your grid (but before you load it):

```
grid.setColAlign(myColAligns.join('|'));
```

For widths, the same applies:

```
grid.setInitWidths(myColWidths.join('|'));
```

**On the back-end**
In ExcelWriter.java, debug through

```
headerPrint(ExcelXmlParser parser)
```

and make sure the your alignments are coming through here:

```
String al = cells[j].getAlign();
```

The col widths are also set in this same function. I did a little customization because it didn't seem like the sizes were comparable:

```
sheet.setColumnView(j, (int)(widths[j]/6.53)); // I replaced  "*scale/sumWidth" with /6.53, which is a strange num, but it works! ;
```